# Is there a cleaner way of caching data

Tags: c#, clean-code

We've started implementing some caching code in our MVC project.  We've derived from .Net's ObjectCache to store it in a SQL database.

What we do right now is in each method we want to cache we have code like this:

```
public StatusCounts GetCounts()
{
   var cache = new SqlCache<StatusCounts>("mykey");
   if(cache.HasCachedData())
      return cache.GetCachedData();

   var data = StatusRepository.GetCounts();

   cache.SetData(data, DateTime.Now.AddHours(2));
}
```

As far as caching goes, it works. But my concern is it seems like now GetCounts has multiple responsibilities. It's no longer just calculating counts, it's getting them from a cache (if they exist) and saving them to a cache before returning.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to push the cache checking responsibility back up to the `StatusRepository`?

Comment: You're right, it should be further down the repository. The code above was simplified. There might be other things going on between just pulling straight from the repo.  But in most cases, it should just be in the repo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can separate the cache initialization from returning the value, and implement the cache initialization in a generic way:

```
public StatusCounts GetCounts()
{
   var cache = GetInitializedCache<StatusCounts>("mykey",StatusRepository.GetCounts,2);
   return cache.GetCachedData();
}

private SqlCache<T> GetInitializedCache<T>(string key,Function<T> getData,double hours)
{
   var cache = new SqlCache<T>(key);
   if(!cache.HasCachedData())
   {
      T data = getData();
      cache.SetData(data, DateTime.Now.AddHours(hours));
   }
   return cache;
}
```

That will separate the concerns of caching and calculating the values as well as giving you a reusable function. Of course, the method body of `GetCounts` is still aware of the caching mechanics, and if you want to avoid that too, @Peri's answer maybe the right approach (for the price of having to introduce a non-trivial third-party component).

Comment: I really don't like this, this code is far more confusing and nonobvious in intention. I would much rather work with a codebase similar to the op's "dumb" code.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic: feel free to suggest better method names to make the intentions more clear. But don't forget the OP wrote he has similar code in lots of methods - so the original code contains lots of duplicated code snippets. My suggestion adresses this, now one can reuse that cache initialization in many places, making the code much more DRY.

Answer (score 4):

I would try to implement it using AOP. You could try Castle.Windsor's Interceptors or mechanism other IoC container have. That way you implement caching in one place only (Interceptor) and there is no sign of cache in your method.

http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Interceptors&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Comment: I feel this would lead to more complex code than explicitely indicating that `getCounts` actually handle caching. With AOP, `getCounts` still manage caching (even indirectly), thus is subject to all caching errors/exceptions/etc. Looks a little like "hide it under the carpet so no one sees it and it looks like it's clean"

Comment: I strongly disagree. Putting same code in every method is bad. Look at that method above. 4 lines of code for caching and one line of real business code. Same as when people do Log.Trace("Entering method xxx with parameters x, y, z"), Log.Trace("Leaving method XXX with result YYY). That's not what you want to do in your business logic code. That's infrastructure!

Comment: IMO the difference is that log doesn't have any effect to the returned/processed values. Those lines doesn't have to be copy/pasted, they can be factorized somewhere (see Doc Brown answer). What I try to emphasis here is that when looking at code, I find that explicitely seeing the cache layer is better than wondering if some AOP is doing something to my value/param/returns

Comment: @ClementHerreman I don't see any way around `getCounts()` dealing with caching exception, if you want to keep the same semantics.

Comment: @ClementHerman: You can decorate methods with some attribute to enable caching. And in your interceptor check if attribute is present I guess. But that could slow things down.

Comment: @svick I don't see any either, as its responsability is to either get from the cache, or recalculate it and cache it., but I think that's fine.
@ Peri then with such decorations I don't really see the benefit of AOP vs its overhead/dependency/complexity increase. Isn't it almost the same as explicitely handling caching, as in Doc Brown's answer?

Comment: To me it is a lot cleaner if I just add [Interceptor("cache")] or sth like that to the class. Doc Brown's answer is per this class only. What if I have another class? Add same method (GetInitializedCache) to each class? No? So maybe create another class and put that method there and then instantiate it in every class that needs caching or make it static so that all classes can use it? But how will you unit test it then? You would have to inject that class using property/ctor injection and mock/stub it in unit tests. That sounds more complicated then just adding attribute.

Comment: To continue I sill prefer dependency injection then what Doc Brown suggested as this solution is not testable at all.

Comment: @Peri: my solution is not less or more testable than the original code (it was never intended to be). It gives an outline for *a first step* to make the code more DRY. Further refactoring may make sense if more testability is needed (which should be easier when the cache code is already in one place). Using AOP the way suggested by you is not "a completely different solution", it needs - probably generic - caching code, which could actually look very similar to my outline.

Comment: @DocBrown: Sorry I didn't mean to say that you solution is that bad or bad at all. I know that OP didn't ask for testable code. You solution is the simplest one and a lot better then what OP had. I was just responding to svick why I think I prefer my solution. Even though it may seem more complicated or as some say 'magic'.

Answer (score 0):

I built a little tool for this some time ago, https://code.google.com/p/mbcache, that we use with success in our shop. It uses AOP the way @Peri describes behind the scenes.

No matter using this or another tool, I would defiantly favor AOP for this. As you write yourself, you shouldn't mix responsibilities within your classes (extract caching logic to a seperate method don't matter IMHO - it just moves the dependency instead of getting rid of it).